# selecting required fields in mongodb using monk

Tags: mongodb, monk

I am able to retrieve only selected fields in mongodb using Monk using the below method

```
collection.find({}, 'Name Age -_id', function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

This works fine, but i am facing issues when i add one more option in the query it throws `fn should be a function` error as it expects third parameter to be success callback function

I get this error when i try

```
collection.find({},{limit:5}, 'Name Age -_id', function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
```

I tried using on success function but still got the same error

```
collection. find({} ,  { limit: 5 }, 'Name Age -_id').on('success', function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
collection.find({ },  { limit : 5, fields : "Name Age -_id"  },   function (err,data) {
 res.json(docs);
});
```

Comment: thanks Hiren
Any tutorial link suggestion for learning monk ?

Comment: is it possible to select name age and _id and eliminate the rest?

Comment: Means you want to remove other fields from DB ?

Comment: No i meant i want to select _id also
Btw i googled and got a solution and posted as answer thanks :)

Comment: I thought you want to exclude id field . So as per your question, i added -_id in answer also. Never mind. Good Luck

Comment: yeah your answer solved the question :) Just after posting the question i realized that i needed `_id` also.
did not want to change the question, luckily found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a cleaner and more readable way to do this,

```
        query1={'userType':'mobile'}; //What to select
         query2={limit : 2, fields : "name age _id"} //limit and fields to select
        collection.find(query1,query2,
        function(error,mobile_users){
            if(error)
                response.send(error)
            else{
                response.send(mobile_users);
            }
        });
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wants to **select fields including _id**, you can try the below solution

```
collection. find({},{ limit: 5 , fields : 'Name Age _id'}, function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
```

This will select and return only Name, Age and _id fields